# Where to put utils.py

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, python-import

Dear all I am running the first Azure tutorial for the MNIST dataset.

It says that the utils.py should be in the same folder as the code. I tried to install python-utils in myconda-environment, but that did not solve the problem. After using pip install utils I rather made it worse :-(

It is probably simple but I am stuck.
How would you do that on the notebook running on:

1. locally
2. in a Azure notebook

I use Anaconda with a separate environment running the Azure SDK and python 3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, I think the first Azure tutorial for the MNIST dataset is [Tutorial: Train an image classification model with Azure Machine Learning service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/tutorial-train-models-with-aml).

You can find all of source codes via the link inside the tutorial as below at [here](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/tree/master/tutorials).

> **Get the notebook**
>
> For your convenience, this tutorial is available as a [***Jupyter notebook***](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/tutorials/img-classification-part1-training.ipynb). Run the `tutorials/img-classification-part1-training.ipynb` notebook either in Azure Notebooks or in your own Jupyter notebook server.

Here is the source code of [`utils.py`](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/tutorials/utils.py).

```
# Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the MIT License.

import gzip
import numpy as np
import struct


# load compressed MNIST gz files and return numpy arrays
def load_data(filename, label=False):
    with gzip.open(filename) as gz:
        struct.unpack('I', gz.read(4))
        n_items = struct.unpack('>I', gz.read(4))
        if not label:
            n_rows = struct.unpack('>I', gz.read(4))[0]
            n_cols = struct.unpack('>I', gz.read(4))[0]
            res = np.frombuffer(gz.read(n_items[0] * n_rows * n_cols), dtype=np.uint8)
            res = res.reshape(n_items[0], n_rows * n_cols)
        else:
            res = np.frombuffer(gz.read(n_items[0]), dtype=np.uint8)
            res = res.reshape(n_items[0], 1)
    return res


# one-hot encode a 1-D array
def one_hot_encode(array, num_of_classes):
    return np.eye(num_of_classes)[array.reshape(-1)]
```

If you want to import it in an Azure Jupyter Notebook, please see my steps below.

1. Move into your project page, and click the `New` buttom and select the `Blank File`.
   [image]
2. Then name the file `utils.py` and press `Enter` key.
   [image]
3. Select the file and click `Edit File`.
   [image]
4. Copy and paste the content of `utils.py` from the tutorial Github repo, and click `Save File`.
   [image]
5. Create a Notebook to test `import utils`, it works.
   [image]

So `# make sure utils.py is in the same directory as this code` means as the figure below.

[image]